# How to share some data from backend (express) to frontend (react) in same app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

My app is an express app with react js for view. I have used client side routing using react-router. Now there is a requirement that I need to get some remote config and decide, based on the key-value info, whether or not to display a page. How can I share this information from express side to react js? The remote config reading module can be called from nodejs backend (express).

The app structure is currently like below:

> public > jsx > view components including one having `Route` info for navigation
>
> index.js (I start the server here by wrapping it with express object)

```
app = express();
app.use(someModule(options))
```

And I can retrieve the config from `someModule.remoteConfig.get('key')`

How can I pass this key information from index.js to affect my Route jsx component so that I can use it for some decisions? Every call to `someModule.remoteConfig.get('key')` will return latest value from remote config (the `someModule` is injected with remote config updates by the framework every 5 minutes.), and I can not reimport this module elsewhere like jsx files for example, somehow I need to export this for global use in app, but not sure how to. If I can get access to express `request` object also, I can use that like `req.app.someModule.remoteConfig.get('key')`.

One way I think is to write a route in express side, and make fetch calls from JSX. That route handler will return the config object, but is there a better or recommended way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since your remote config keeps changing, it should be exposed as an API that your client can perform an http request.

Comment: The `someModule` is injected with remote config updates by the framework every 5 minutes.